# Server 2008 use net start/stop without administrator prompt

Tags: windows-server-2008

The title says it all. I need to be able to start and stop a specific service via the normal (non-administrator) command prompt. Is there a way to give access to one user to start and stop this specific service with net start/stop? Currently I just get "access denied".

Answer (score 1):

No. This is a security feature built into server 2008. You can open an elevated prompt by simply right clicking the CMD program icon and selecting run as administrator. (provided you are in fact an administrator!)

Comment: I know how to open an elevated prompt. But I need to do this from a normal prompt. In the end, I need to do it remotely.

Comment: I dont recomend this but the only other thing you could do is disable 'User Access Control' this can be done via the control panel > select Control Panel Home and in the search box on the top right type UAC - the rest is simple. Why are you using a batch file to do this? does computer management not do this for you?

Comment: I don't want to turn off User Access Control. I am doing this because I need to stop and then restart a service as part of a build and deployment process.

Comment: Would it not make more sense to create and execute a powershell script?

Comment: Another idea could you not have your deployment create a scheduled task to execute the batch file as system or another administrator user?

Comment: How could I do it with a powershell script?

Comment: For a scheduled task, you can check the box "Run with highest privilages" additionally if you are running this from your machine, and you are a local admin on the machine, you can run `sc \\server stop svcName`

Answer (score 0):

I use SlickRun (Bayden Systems) to launch a command window that has Administrator privileges.  http://www.bayden.com/SlickRun/

Comment: I need to do this non-interactively.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at [PsService](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897542).  It will allow you to specify a user as well as control a service remotely.

Comment: I believe that PsService will no longer do this in a Server 2008 environment. I think that I tried it, though I can't remember right now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a three-step process.

`net use \\ip\ipc$ * /user:username

sc \\ip stop service

sc \\ip start service`

The first command establishes credentials with the server in question. If both are on the same domain and you're a domain admin/have administrator rights, then you may be able to exclude the first command. Replace * with the password for no prompt (insecure!!).

Answer (score -1):

I know this is really old but I faced the same situation, and hopefully this will help someone else who stumbles upon it.  You in fact CAN use Net Start/stop from a non-admin command prompt.

You must first add "everyone" to the service and give it start/stop permissions.

Comment: Oh man. While that *will* work, that's a dangerous proposition. You're allowing anyone - authenticated or not - to kill a service at will. Yikes.